# How to add a html statement inside a html variable using php?

Tags: php, html

currently i have a image html statement and i would like to add it inside the html

```
$html=file_get_contents('../template/'.$html);
    $img="<img src='http://localhost/fyp/ga/test.php?=$ga'>";
    file_put_contents($html,$img);
```

however, this causes a warning from browser, also, it will append the img statement after  , so how to add it inside using php ?  Thank you.

```
$img="<img src='http://localhost/fyp/ga/test.php?=$ga'>";
```

it get a warning like this:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(<p> <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> <!-- Facebook sharing information tags --></p> <p> <meta content="*|MC:SUBJECT|*" property="og:title" /> </p> <p> <title></title> <style type="text/css"> /* Client-specific Styles */ #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */ body{width:100% !important;} .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */ body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes. */ /* Reset Styles */ body{margin:0; padding:0;} img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;} table td{border-collapse:collapse;} #backgroundTable{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;} in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\mail\send.php on line 47
```

Comment: What does the file you open with `file_get_contents` look like? Where do you need the image added in that file?

Comment: it is an html file. I need to add it inside the <body></body> thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suppose that you have a placeholder inside your html. e.g. {IMAGE}, than you can simple replace this placeholder with

```
<?php
  $html = str_replace("{IMAGE}","<img src='http://localhost/fyp/ga/test.php?=".$ga."'>",$html);
?>
```